# CentOS6 /Rhel 6 boot process

Tags: centos, boot, upstart

I need some help to understand the boot process. I am reading this documentation which should be the same, please correct me if I am wrong https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s2-boot-init-shutdown-jobs.html

I am using centos 6 for example and there is no event.d directory, am I missing something? I dont have a rhel 6 to test this on. So, since Rhel6 Centos 6 is using upstart where are the job definitions then?

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 6 uses a mix of upstart and traditional SYSV INIT.

I've not used upstart, so this is speculative.

All of the servers I've got access to have /etc/event.d and have the upstart RPM installed.

Do a RPM -qa | grep upstart to see if the RPM is installed. If not, install it and see if /etc/event.d shows up.

If it is, no clue.

Comment: I double checked that, upstart is installed...